# Unable to upload VHD to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, vhd

I have a local VirtualBox VM that I want to migrate and setup on Azure. I converted the VMDK files to VHD using command:

```
vboxmanage clonehd D-Drive.vmdk D-Drive.vhd --format VHD
```

Now I am trying to upload the VHD file to Azure using Azure Storage Explorer and it is failing with message:

```
Failed to upload '/Users/xxxx/APPcloud/D-Drive.vhd' to disk 'APP_D-Drive' in resource group 'APPcloudResGrp': Unable to create disk: Error:The upload size in bytes 32740472832 - 512 bytes for the VHD footer (32740472320 in this case) must be a multiple of MiB.
```

Any advice as to how I can resolve this? I tried resizing the vmdk file to a nice multiple MB but vboxmanage fails with VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED error.

FYI VirtualBox and Azure Storage Explorer are being run in a MacBook Pro, Latest MacOS

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to convert the file from vmdk to vhd and set the format to fixed as this is needed for Azure:

```
qemu-img convert -f vmdk -o subformat=fixed -O vpc vm-104-disk-0.vmdk vm-104-disk-0.vhd
```